# Sending emails without using SMTP Server

Tags: c++, smtp, sendmail

I want that my program could send email without using Microsoft Outlook or other programs or SMTP server. Is that possible? Can I send email without connecting to SMTP server?

Comment: Yes, you can talk directly to the target server. Which is of course SMTP, but you don't need another server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't *by definition*, since email gets through the recipient at least passing through the SMTP server of his/her domain.

You may send it directly to the recipient's SMTP server instead of going through the ISP's server getting its data through DNS (which is basically re-implementing a local SMTP server on your own), but it's not a good idea, since many target servers will refuse to accept your mails due to spam concerns (your connection will probably come through graylisted "residential" IP addresses, it won't have a rDNS record, ...).

Comment: so it means i will have to talk with the smtp server okay i see.. how can i know what the target server? for example how can i tell what is the target server smtp of this email xxxxxx@hotmail.com?
edit: your not suggesting me to use this way?

Comment: @DanRevah: using the DNS MX record of the domain of your recipient. But, again, that would mean implementing a simple SMTP server on your own (which isn't a good idea - if you really want to use this method you should just use any ready-made lightweight SMTP server), and you'll probably get a ton of rejected mail for the reasons I already explained.

Comment: @DanRevah DNS, on UNIX the simplest way to get this information is using the command `host`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Why would he need to implement a DNS server, or a SMTP server?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: accepting email and re-sending it to the recipient's SMTP servers is one of the basic duties of an SMTP server ("mail relay"), so he's better off just using a ready-made one. --EDIT-- I saw now that I wrote "DNS" instead of "SMTP". Fixed

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yes it is, but the same way you don't need to build a traffic light to cross the street, there is no reason to implement a SMTP server. All he needs is a SMTP client.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: There are lots of libraries that do that. *Sending* mail through SMTP is pretty easy, but the other things a server is doing is hard.

Comment: so what you are saying is that if i will use a ready-made smtp server then i won't get any rejected mails?

Comment: @DanRevah: No! You will get rejected emails anyway, since several antispam checks are on your IP and associated rDNS record (if present), via DNSBL, blacklists, graylists [& co.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-spam_techniques#Automated_techniques_for_e-mail_administrators). That doesn't change if you use a different program.

Comment: @DanRevah: by the way, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Matteo Italia what i am trying accomplish is to add my program a simple "contact us" form and automaticlly send mails if the progam will behave unexpectedly

Comment: @DanRevah: Then the proper way to do that would probably to spawn the predefined user mail agent filled with the information you want to send so that your user can choose whether he wants to send this information or not. You may do this using a `mailto:target@host.com` link and can even prefill the object, body and recipient.

Comment: @DanRevah: or you could just create a web contact form for this, uploading the additional information via a POST request. Also, you could configure a specific mail server for this purpose, giving the program the credentials to authenticate on it (although I think that the web approach is more flexible).